# Seating people at two round tables

Tags: combinatorics

In how many ways can $k$ people out of $n$ be seated at one round table and the remaining $n-k$ people at another table?

In my specific case, there are 14 people and I want to know the way to seat 8 of them at one round table and the others at another round table?

Comment: Minor English lesson (assuming the OP is not a native speaker):  An individual sits "at" a table; a group of people can sit either "at" or "around" a table.  But sitting "on" a table means you're actually on *top* of the table, along with the plates and the silverware.

Comment: **1.** Are the two tables distinct ? **2.** Do both tables have $8$ seats ?

Answer (score 2):

Choose 8 people out of 14, and put them at the first table. The number of possible combinations equals:

$${14 \choose 8} = 3003$$

Then, there are $8!$ ways for these 8 people to be seated, and $6!$ for the other 6. However, since it is a round table, we must divide by 8 and 6 respectively. As such, we get:

$${14 \choose 8} \cdot 7! \cdot 5! = 1,816,214,400$$